# How to create and use my own golang package locally to get this test to run?

Tags: go

I'm new to golang working through coding exercises and I have all the following files in a directory called leap.  I'm using gvm to run the golang executable (version 1.4), using a command such as "go test leap_test.go".

When I do *go test leap_test.go* I get the following results:

```
# command-line-arguments
leap_test.go:5:2: open /home/user/go/leap/leap: no such file or directory
FAIL    command-line-arguments [setup failed]
```

1. How do I include the IsLeap() function so that the tests run correctly.
2. Why is cases_test.go even included?  It seems like leap_test.go is all you'd need for tests.

**cases_test.go**

```
package leap

// Source: exercism/x-common
// Commit: 945d08e Merge pull request #50 from soniakeys/master

var testCases = []struct {
    year        int
    expected    bool
    description string
}{
    {1996, true, "leap year"},
    {1997, false, "non-leap year"},
    {1998, false, "non-leap even year"},
    {1900, false, "century"},
    {2400, true, "fourth century"},
    {2000, true, "Y2K"},
}
```

**leap_test.go**

```
package leap

import (
    "testing"
    "./leap"
)

var testCases = []struct {
    year        int
    expected    bool
    description string
}{
    {1996, true, "a vanilla leap year"},
    {1997, false, "a normal year"},
    {1900, false, "a century"},
    {2400, true, "an exceptional century"},
}

    func TestLeapYears(t *testing.T) {
        for _, test := range testCases {
            observed := IsLeap(test.year)
            if observed != test.expected {
                t.Fatalf("%v is %s", test.year, test.description)
            }
        }
    }
```

**leap.go**

```
package leap

import(
    "fmt"
)

func IsLeap(year int) bool {
  return true
}
```

Comment: Plain ol' `go test` should do it if you have a sane `GOPATH` set. Normally only `go run` takes *.go file names, the others like `go install`, `go build`, etc (normally) take package name(s) as arguments. Oh, and relative import paths are generally avoided. Read [How To Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Command go](http://golang.org/cmd/go/)
>
> [Test packages](http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Test_packages)
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
> go test [-c] [-i] [build and test flags] [packages] [flags for test binary]
> ```

For example,

**leap/leap.go**

```
package leap

func IsLeap(year int) bool {
    return true
}
```

**leap/leap_test.go**

```
package leap

import (
    "testing"
)

var testCases = []struct {
    year        int
    expected    bool
    description string
}{
    {1996, true, "a vanilla leap year"},
    {1997, false, "a normal year"},
    {1900, false, "a century"},
    {2400, true, "an exceptional century"},
}

func TestLeapYears(t *testing.T) {
    for _, test := range testCases {
        observed := IsLeap(test.year)
        if observed != test.expected {
            t.Fatalf("%v is %s", test.year, test.description)
        }
    }
}
```

If `$GOPATH` is set to include the `leap` package directory:

```
$ go test leap
--- FAIL: TestLeapYears (0.00s)
    leap_test.go:22: 1997 is a normal year
FAIL
FAIL    leap    0.003s
$
```

Or, if you `cd` to the `leap` package directory:

```
$ go test
--- FAIL: TestLeapYears (0.00s)
    leap_test.go:22: 1997 is a normal year
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    so/leap 0.003s
$
```